# String "loss" being passed to metric_name() instead of metric name

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I'm following a tutorial, but I'm getting the error:

`ValueError: Could not interpret metric identifier: loss`

at:
`\keras\src\metrics\__init__.py:205, in get(identifier)`

It seems like in the wrapper.py line 532 `metric_name(key)` should receive the name of a loss function, but it's actually receiving the string "loss"

Here is the relevant code for the error:

```
def buildNetwork():
    classificator = Sequential()
    classificator.add(Dense(units = 20, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform', input_shape=(30,)))
    classificator.add(Dense(units = 20, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
    classificator.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid'))
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, weight_decay=0.000001)
    classificator.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
    return classificator


classifier = KerasClassifier(model=buildNetwork,batch_size=10,epochs=100, loss='binary_crossentropy')

score = cross_val_score(estimator=classifier, X=data, y=truth, cv=10, error_score='raise')
```

If inside `keras_metric_get` I manually set `identifier = "binary_crossentropy"` it works fine

I don't know if it's a compatibility problem, but I have Keras 3.0.8, TF 2.15.0 and SciKeras 0.12.0

Answer (score 1):

From the [SciKeras quickstart documentation](https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/quickstart.html#training-a-model) you should pass to `KerasClassifier()` the model and the loss. From the [KerasClassifier documentation](https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/generated/scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier.html#scikeras-wrappers-kerasclassifier) you can also pass the optimizer and the metrics.

I would avoid defining the loss both in `buildNetwork()` and in `KerasClassifier()`. I would mimic the example in the [SciKeras quickstart documentation](https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/quickstart.html#training-a-model) where only the network is defined in `buildNetwork()` and everything else (optimizer, loss and metrics) is defined outside.

```
def buildNetwork():
    classificator = Sequential()
    classificator.add(Dense(units = 20, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform', input_shape=(30,)))
    classificator.add(Dense(units = 20, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
    classificator.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid'))
    return classificator


classifier = KerasClassifier(
    model=buildNetwork,
    batch_size=10,
    epochs=100, 
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, weight_decay=0.000001),
    metrics=['binary_accuracy'],
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having this problem because of a version incompatibility, after uninstalling and installing everything again it worked fine